# How to control Os iterations python

Tags: python, iteration

I wrote the following code to make an inventory of every files in a library. the idea is that the 3 columns have infromation about the file. 
1) complete path 2) name of the parent directory 3) filename.

```
import os
import openpyxl

def crearlista (*arg, **kw):
    inventario = openpyxl.Workbook(encoding = "Utf-8")
    sheet = inventario.active
    i = 1
    f = 1
    e = ""
    for  dirpath, subdirs,  files in os.walk(*arg, **kw):
        for name in subdirs:
            e = os.path.join (name)

        for name in files:

            sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value = name
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value = dirpath
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value = e
            i = i + 1   

    inventario.save("asd3.xlsx")

crearlista("//media//rayeus/Datos/Mis Documentos/Nueva carpeta/", topdown=False)
```

The problem is that it iterates first through the files in the first folder and after that starts filling the 'e' variable with the name of the first folder.
That way it starts writing late the names in the folder column. And it writes theme as many times as files in the next folder, not as many files there are in THAT folder.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Isn't this the same as your last question?

Comment: Just a general comment: consider using English in your code. A somewhat random combination of English and Spanish will be quite confusing if you end up building anything larger.

Comment: Si, definitivamente utiliza English! What is e = os.path.join(name) for exactly? Shouldn't it be: e = os.path.join(e, name)?

Comment: yes DSM but i didn't found an answer and some people told me that it was hard to undersand it so i tried to reformulate it in a more simple way.

Comment: e is supossed to store the name of the folder that contains the files that are being iterated, so it should be "a" for all the files in the a folder "b" for all the files in b etc etc.

currently it is  "" for all the files in a folder "a" for all the files in b folder "b" for all the files in c folder etc etc

Comment: Did you read help(os.walk)??? In your example, e is the last name of all subdirectories contained in directory whoose name is in dirpath. To have the name of folder that contains all listed files do: e = os.path.basename(dirpath)